# Search and replace hash value. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have the following in the beginning of a file

```
<?php
return array(
    'DB' => array(
        'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
        'host' => '172.17.1.47',
```

where `172.17.1.47` can be anything. I would like to change whatever it is set to, to the content in `$ip`. So I have tried

```
ip="1.2.3.4"
sed -i "s/\'host\' => \'.*\',/$ip/g" /tmp/LocalConfiguration.php
sed -i "s/\(\'host\' => \'\).*/\1$ip\'/g" /tmp/LocalConfiguration.php
```

but is doesn't change anything.

**Question**

Can anyone see what is wrong? Or know a better way to do it?

Comment: No need to escape the quotes in the `sed` expression when the quotes are in the search field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting seems to be messed up. You can use:

```
ip="1.2.3.4"
sed -i.bak -r "s/('host' => ')[^']*'/\1$ip'/" file.php
cat file.php

<?php
return array(
    'DB' => array(
        'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
        'host' => '1.2.3.4',
```

Comment: `[^']*` matches 0 or more of any character that not a single quote so basically it matches IP between `'` and `'`